# dependent t-test giving opposite result

Tags: r, sampling

I have a dataframe as below.

```
> spider
   participant   group anxiety
1            1 picture      30
2            2 picture      35
3            3 picture      45
4            4 picture      40
5            5 picture      50
6            6 picture      35
7            7 picture      55
8            8 picture      25
9            9 picture      30
10          10 picture      45
11          11 picture      40
12          12 picture      50
13           1    real      40
14           2    real      35
15           3    real      50
16           4    real      55
17           5    real      65
18           6    real      55
19           7    real      50
20           8    real      35
21           9    real      30
22          10    real      50
23          11    real      60
24          12    real      39
```

If I carry out independent t-test, get the below result :

I get p > 0.05, so the null hypothesis cant be rejected, which is of no difference between the groups. **Fair enough**.

```
> wide.t.test

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  md$picture and md$real
t = -1.6813, df = 21.385, p-value = 0.1072
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -15.648641   1.648641
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
       40        47
```

In case of dependent t-test on same dataset, result is following :

Here p < 0.05, and null hypothesis of no difference between the groups, is to be rejected. **What does this signify ??**

```
> depend.t.test

    Paired t-test

data:  spider$anxiety by spider$group
t = -2.4725, df = 11, p-value = 0.03098
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -13.2312185  -0.7687815
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                     -7
```

Comment: Is it the same data? `data:  md$picture and md$real` in your `wide.t.test` vs. `data:  spider$anxiety by spider$group` in your `depend.t.test`...

Comment: second one is a paired test, which check if the mean difference of the different pairs is 0 while first one does not take into account the fact that there are pairs, it checks if the 2 vectors (values for 1st group, values for 2nd group) have same mean

Comment: Why are you surprised that different tests give different results? A paired t-test has better power than a Welch test. The decision which one to use is not arbitrary. It depends on your experimental setup, i.e., whether your samples are actually paired.

Comment: @Roland, in my case participants are same for both groups. In that case what should I go for and why ?

Comment: @LeoP. Yes, they are the same.

Comment: If you measured each subject twice (e.g., before and after a treatment) you have a paired design. You might benefit from attending a statistics lecture or reading a statistics textbook. This is quite elementary.

Comment: @Roland, yes i am referring to Andy Field's book on stats.

The example is from that book only, but it suggests a Independent t-test on the dataset. The dataset measures anxiety level caused to people from real spider vs a picture of spider.

Comment: Field has written more than one book. Which book, which edition, which page number? Can you give the information he states about the experiment?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the data from table 9.1 p 362 of *Discovering Statistics Using R* by Field, Miles and Field ("spiderLong") then the book says there are 24 participants, each given one treatment. In that case it's unpaired and the independent samples test makes sense.

If it's the data in table 9.2 ("spiderWide" - which is actually the same data but now pretending it's two measurements on the same person -- the text says "let's imagine that...") then it is paired and you need a paired test.

When the two values within each pair have a positive correlation, the paired test would be expected to have better power.